# Soul trap does not work - black soul gem

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Soul trap does not work. I have the soul trap spell and I cast it on the enemy (human). The enemy shimmers and I kill them within a few seconds, but there's no further effect and my black soul gem is still empty.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have mods installed? If yes, did you try without them?

Comment: It is usually easier to enchant a weapon with soul trap and kill with it.

Comment: Make sure that the soul you are trying to capture did not go into a smaller soul gem. The easiest way to test this is to empty your inventory of all other soul gems and then try to trap a soul into your Black Soul Gem.

Comment: @ChaseC you can't fit human souls into any other soul gem

Comment: @Nelson Ah, so true. So maybe check your other Black Soul Gems and make sure you're not filling up any of your other Black ones. (I was thinking Grand Soul Gems could capture humanoids. Doh)

Comment: There really isn't a way to mistake this, unless you have the Black Azure Star, and the soul goes into the Azure Star instead of the Black Souls.

Comment: It is possible you fought a magic user and the glow you see is actually their armor spell and you actually missed with your Soul Trap.  Try it on an obviously non-magical user like random Bandit or even a town guard.

Comment: Which NPC was it? I think some are marked as immune. Definitely, the most powerful ones tend to resist soul trap. If, as @Nelson suggests, the glow was due to the NPC casting a spell, you might have missed the "Resisted Soul Trap" message, or even might have actually just missed the target. I've had that happen occasionally when soul trapping mudcrabs.

Answer (score -3):

I think soul traps only work for weaker creatures. I tried this too on a human but it didn't work. Instead try using an enchanted weapon with soul capturing ability or buy soul filled soul gems. You can also go on random side adventures and many a times you will find filled soul gems (even black soul gems filled with soul) depending on your level.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Humoids can indeed be soul trapped, but only in a Black Soul Gem or the Black Azura's Star.  @soham: when you tried to trap the human, you probably didn't have any Black Soul Gems in your inventory.